# stunnel Issue SSL3_GET_ERROR / SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO

Tags: ssl

I have set up Stunnel as SSL Wrapper for googlemmil from Redhat Enterprise Linux 7.2.

The stunnel.conf:

```
output = /var/log/stunnel.log
cert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/2019stunnel.pem
client = yes
sslVersion = TLSv1
;fips=no
[ssmtp]
accept = 1925
connect=smtp.googlemail.com:587
```

lets me start stunned well.

I have created the file 2019stunnel.pem following the Instructions on Redhat:

make 2019stunnel.pem in the correct directory (certs)

now I tried to telnet localhost 1925; I get a connected, but nothing more.
telnet smtp.googlemail 587 runs very well, I get connected, so I assume it is not a firewall issue.

I checked sslVersion = TLSv1 and sslVersion = all which led to different errors in stunned.log:

```
Service [ssmtp] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:49723
2019.01.04 14:45:01 LOG3[4500:140416608397056]: connect_blocking: connect 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::10:587: Network is unreachable (101)
2019.01.04 14:45:01 LOG5[4500:140416608397056]: connect_blocking: connected 74.125.140.16:587
2019.01.04 14:45:01 LOG5[4500:140416608397056]: Service [ssmtp] connected remote server from 192.168.178.57:44246
2019.01.04 14:45:01 LOG3[4500:140416608397056]: SSL_connect: 140770FC: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
2019.01.04 14:45:01 LOG5[4500:140416608397056]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
2019.01.04 14:54:24 LOG5[4500:140416608249920]: Terminated
```

or

```
Service [ssmtp] accepted connection from 192.168.178.57:57612
2019.01.04 14:54:36 LOG5[7437:139957105055488]: connect_blocking: connected 173.194.76.16:587
2019.01.04 14:54:36 LOG5[7437:139957105055488]: Service [ssmtp] connected remote server from 192.168.178.57:52192
2019.01.04 14:54:36 LOG3[7437:139957105055488]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
2019.01.04 14:54:36 LOG5[7437:139957105055488]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
```

Now Open SSL:

Openssl output:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:1925
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1546610402
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

What do I miss here; what is running wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

stunnel creates a TCP connection to the given server and then **immediately** tries an upgrade to TLS. But port 587 does not expect immediate TLS: instead it expect to start with SMTP on a plain TCP connection and only after the STARTTLS command and its successful reply the socket gets upgraded to TLS. That's why a simple `openssl s_client` will not work against `smtp.googlemail.com:587` the same way it will not work against your stunnel.

If you want immediate TLS use port 465 (smtps) and not 587 (submission). If you want to stay with port 587 you have to specify `protocol smtp` in your stunnel configuration so that stunnel knows that TLS only starts after the STARTTLS.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the parameter protocol smtp is the solution !